# export a php file to excel

Tags: php

How can we set style to the table while export a php file  to excel

using the following code we can export a php file to excel

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$fname."Application.xls");

print "<html xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\">
<style>

@page
    {margin:1.0in .75in 1.0in .75in;
    mso-header-margin:.5in;
    mso-footer-margin:.5in;}
tr
    {mso-height-source:auto;}
col
    {mso-width-source:auto;}
br
    {mso-data-placement:same-cell;
    }

.style0
    {mso-number-format:General;
    text-align:general;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    white-space:nowrap;
    mso-rotate:0;
    mso-background-source:auto;
    mso-pattern:auto;
    color:windowtext;
    font-size:10.0pt;
    font-weight:400;
    font-style:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Arial;
    mso-generic-font-family:auto;
    mso-font-charset:0;
    border:none;
    mso-protection:locked visible;
    mso-style-name:Normal;
    mso-style-id:0;}
td
    {mso-style-parent:style0;
    padding-top:1px;
    padding-right:1px;
    padding-left:1px;
    mso-ignore:padding;
    color:windowtext;
    font-size:10.0pt;
    font-weight:400;
    font-style:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Arial;
    mso-generic-font-family:auto;
    mso-font-charset:0;
    mso-number-format:General;
    text-align:general;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    border:none;
    mso-background-source:auto;
    mso-pattern:auto;
    mso-protection:locked visible;
    white-space:nowrap;
    mso-rotate:0;}
.grids
    {mso-style-parent:style0;
    border:.5pt solid windowtext;}.head{
    font-weight:bold;
}

</style>
<head>
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<x:ExcelWorkbook>
<x:ExcelWorksheets>
<x:ExcelWorksheet>
<x:Name>Application List</x:Name>
<x:WorksheetOptions>
<x:Print>
</x:Print>
</x:WorksheetOptions>
</x:ExcelWorksheet>
</x:ExcelWorksheets>
</x:ExcelWorkbook> 
</xml>
<![endif]--> 
</head>
<body>";

print '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" class="tbl_content">';

print ' <tr class="head" valign="bottom">
                                                        <td align="center" width="7%" height="22"><b>SL No</b></td>
                                                    <td align="left" width="18%"><b>Name Of Party</b></td>
                                                    <td align="left" width="18%"><b>Godown</b></td>
                                                    <td align="center" width="16%" ><b>Invoice No</b></td>
                                                    <td align="center" width="12%"><b>Date</b></td>
                                                    <td align="right" width="17%"><b>Taxable Turnover</b></td>
                                                    <td align="right" width="14%"><b>VAT Amount</b></td>
                                                    <td align="right" width="8%"><b>Cess Amt.</b></td>
                                                    <td align="right" width="16%"><b>Total Turnover</b></td>
                                                </tr>';   

print '</table></body></html>';
```

but the style is not taken when display in browser.

Comment: What library do you use to generate the excel files?

Comment: Please add much more detail to this question. It is extremely hazy. Please give more info about the export process you are using

Answer (score 1):

Check out this lib: [php_writeexcel](http://www.bettina-attack.de/jonny/view.php/projects/php_writeexcel/demo/)